# Using NSSortDescriptor to sort build numbers with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to use `NSSortDescriptor` with Core Data to sort build numbers/software versions (NSStrings). The build numbers are actually just NSStrings but it seems to have a hard time with this. I'm guessing because of the multiple and irregular decimal points.

For example, I would like to sort the following.

```
1.7.6
1.8
1.6.2
1.9.0.1
2.0
```

Each line represents an `NSString`.

How would I do this properly or is there another way I should try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sort descriptor using `localizedStandardCompare:` should produce the intended result:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"buildNumber"
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

`localizedStandardCompare:` is the "Finder-like" comparison and strings containing numbers
are sorted according to their numerical value.

In **Swift:**

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "buildNumber", ascending: true,
            selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
```