# Sort Descriptors not sorting numbers in the form of string - iphone

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor

I have some string saved in core data

@"123", @"1" , @"432", @"90003", @"4567", @"1002"

This needs to be sorted ascending and this is the code i have written

```
NSFetchRequest *request1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [request1 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ABCD" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
            [request1 setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];
            sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"statusIdNo" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
            [request1 setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

            statusArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request1 error:nil];
```

But this code is not sorting it the way required. Am i missing anything here?

**EDIT:**

```
The Required Result : @"1" , @"123", @"432", , @"1002",  @"4567", @"90003"
Whats coming now : @"123"@"432",@"1"  , @"1002",   @"90003", @"4567"
```

One more thing i would like to add is that, the array doesn’t contain the strings as it is. These are core data entity objects. Like example it contains students object say for class X which has all the students’ roll numbers, names and marks as their attributes. And we need to sort it based on roll numbers which is stored as an NSNumber.

Comment: They're strings and I think they're sorted by their ASCII codes.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847240/using-nssortdescriptor-to-sort-build-numbers-with-core-data

Comment: Your code work fine. I checked it. Can't understand what kind of sorting you need.

Comment: checked. I edited my post.

Comment: I think the problem is in other part of your code

Comment: How do you output statusArray? Can you post more code, please.

Comment: StatusArray is used for tableView. I reload the table with this array

Comment: Could you, please, post your data model scheme. It seems to me that you need to use NSSortDescriptor like this @"student.statusIdNo" or something like. But I need to see your scheme

Comment: please, post your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath implementation also

Comment: its actually the -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath itself.. its loading only 4 cells

Comment: This code you posted is ok. I would like to see more, cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation and the model scheme. Just make a screenshot with relationships between the entities. It will be better to understand this situation

Answer (score 3):

In your case use `NSSortDescriptor` like this:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"statusIdNo"
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

more information about this comparison is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

EDIT:

about `setIncludesPendingChanges` from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#jumpTo_29

> A value of YES is not supported in conjunction with the result type
>   NSDictionaryResultType, including calculation of aggregate results
>   (such as max and min). For dictionaries, the array returned from the
>   fetch reflects the current state in the persistent store, and does not
>   take into account any pending changes, insertions, or deletions in the
>   context.
>
> If you need to take pending changes into account for some simple
>   aggregations like max and min, you can instead use a normal fetch
>   request, sorted on the attribute you want, with a fetch limit of 1.

EDIT 2:

my code:

```
- (void) getAllObjects
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request1 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request1 setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"str" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    [request1 setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSArray *statusArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request1 error:nil];

    for (Entity *ent in statusArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", ent.str);
    }
}
```

and result:

```
2014-04-11 20:06:34.454 smth1[8918:60b] 1
2014-04-11 20:06:34.456 smth1[8918:60b] 123
2014-04-11 20:06:34.456 smth1[8918:60b] 432
2014-04-11 20:06:34.457 smth1[8918:60b] 1002
2014-04-11 20:06:34.457 smth1[8918:60b] 4567
2014-04-11 20:06:34.458 smth1[8918:60b] 90003
```

Comment: ok then, just try to comment [request1 setIncludesPendingChanges:NO]; I can make a mistake but I think it affects the result

Comment: it doesnt affect the results in any which way. Infact that makes your fetch more efficient since it doesnt consider pending changes. But anyways, commenting that didnt work as well..

Comment: Another thing. Say suppose there is no fetch here and only an array which i need to sort. It still doesnt sort expected way.

Comment: Maybe try to use NSFetchedResultsController ?